# Django - Triggering creation of other instances when one instance is created

Tags: python, django

I have three models representing a message, plaintext, and ciphertext:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    key = models.ForeignKey(Key, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='messages')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default='')
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='messages')

class Plaintext(models.Model):
    message = models.OneToOneField(
        Message,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True
    )
    text = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')


class Ciphertext(models.Model):
    message = models.OneToOneField(
        Message,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        primary_key=True
    )
    text = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
```

I would like a `Plaintext` and a `Ciphertext` instance to be automatically created whenever a `Message` is created. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: I've tried overriding `save` on `Message`. I was wondering if there was a standard way to do this.

Comment: You'll want to take a look at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/signals/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have everything you need just by using a [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) signal:

```
from .models import Plaintext, Ciphertext


def create_plain_and_cipher_text(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Plaintext.objects.create(message=instance)
        Ciphertext.objects.create(message=instance)
```

You don't need or have to override the `.save()` method on `Message` at all.

Fortunately, `post_save` tells us whether or not a new instance was `created` or not, allowing you to create the related model instances only when a new object is created, and not every time a `Message` object is saved.

Comment: I would just like to clarify something that isn't immediately clear from the documentation: If I use the `@receiver` decorator, I don't have to call `Signal.connect`, right?

Comment: Correct. You just have to make sure your signal code is registered.

Answer (score 0):

By dynamically getting model constructors, you won't have to worry about loading order. You can override the save method or use a [post save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#post-save) to trigger the create actions.

```
from django.apps import apps

class Message(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        PLAIN_TEXT_MODEL = apps.get_model(app_label='your_app_name_here', model_name='Plaintext')
        CIPHER_TEXT_MODEL = apps.get_model(app_label='your_app_name_here', model_name='Ciphertext')
        new_pt_model = PLAIN_TEXT_MODEL.objects.create(some_field=self.some_field_in_message_model,some_other_field = 1)
        CIPHER_TEXT_MODEL.objects.create(some_field="Something")
        super(Message,self).save(*args,**kwargs) # call default save method
```

To use a signal -

```
from django.db.models import signals

class Message(models.Model):
    ...

def your_callable_function(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # do something, create other model instances, etc

signals.post_save.connect(your_callable_function, sender=Message)
```

Comment: Models are registered in [`ModelBase.__new__()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/6670da75ff8a59b2ec0b465846e3f76aab9155b2/django/db/models/base.py#L283). If you directly import the model, you don't have to worry about loading order, since loading the model into the registry is a side-effect of importing it. There's no reason to use `apps.get_model()` unless you dynamically need to fetch different model classes.

Comment: If these models are in the same `models.py` and defined in the order the OP listed then a `NameError` will be raised.

Comment: Right, it's a single file. There is still no need to use `apps.get_model()`, all class definitions are run before the `.save()` method is ever called. It's trivial to test that using the models in a method will in fact _not_ result in a `NameError` even if the method itself is defined before the class it references.

Comment: Good call, having built some similar methods in earlier Django (1.4?) I had to do this (with an earlier version of `get_model`). Just updated it without the calls and no more problems.